# Search for attribute value in xaml file using linq in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, xaml

I know basic about getting node values from a xml file, but in a complicated xaml file I don't know how to write my linq query.

This is a sample of xaml I'm using:

```
<Activity something:something = " 2010" x:class = "example"..........>
    <x:Members>
        <x:Property Name= "aaaaa" Type = "Inargument" />
    </x:Members>
    <sap:abcdef>1322,2222</sap:abcdef>
    <prwab:work sap2010:Annotation.AnnotationText = " I need this value" Active = "False" CreatedOn = "2014-07-09" ID = "123456" DisplayName = "theNameIneed">
        <prwab:work.activity>
            <prwais:collectingActivity sap2010:Annotation.AnnotationText = "I also need this value" >   CreatedOn = "2014-07-09" ID = "1234232" DisplayName = "Ineed2">
                <prwais .....>
                </prwais>     
            </prwis:collectingActivity>
        </prwab:work.activity>
    </prwab:work>
</Activity>
```

I need to get the data in the lines that contain attribute "sap2010:Annotation.AnnotationText", and the value is going to be the content of sap2010:Annotation.AnnotationText, and key is going to be the attribute "ID" and  attribute "displayName" in that line.

Here is the query I have right now, I know it's wrong but I don't know the proper way to write it:

```
var dataNodes = XElement.Load(file, LoadOptions.None);
 Console.WriteLine("Loaded xaml file: " + file);
 var dataNodesDictionary = from dataRecord in (dataNodes.Elements("prwab") && dataNodes.Elements("prwais"))//this line is wrong, but I dont know how to write it, since annotation may appears in different elements, and even if I only use "prwab" for testing, i still get nothing
                                  where dataRecord.Attributes("Annotation.AnnotationText") != null
                                  select new DictionaryEntry
                                  {
                                      Key = dataRecord.Attribute("DisplayName").Value.ToString() + "|" + dataRecord.Attribute("ID").Value.ToString(),
                                      Value = dataRecord.Attribute("Annotation.AnnotationText").Value.ToString(),

                                  };
```

Can some one help me please, thanks.

Comment: Could you paste the real XAML file please? Why exactly do you need to parse the XAML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find all elements that have the attribute. Then pull the attribute values.

```
// Name of the attributes we are looking
string ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/presentation";
XName name = XName.Get("Annotation.AnnotationText", ns);


XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

var q = doc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Attribute(name) != null)
    .Select(e => new DictionaryEntry { Key = e.Attribute("ID").Value, Value = e.Attribute(name).Value });
```

**SIDE NOTE:** In the future please paste in valid XML so it is easier for others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It works really well, thank you so much! Sorry, one more question: what is that ns string for? I can't run it without it.

Comment: The attribute you are searching for is in the namespace sap2010, which I googled and found is usually `http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/presentation`, it should also be defined at the top of your xaml file. So when searching for that attribute, the name alone is not enough. You must also include the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is XAML, you'll have a problem:

The attribute you're looking for can be written using a tag:

```
<prwab:work sap2010:Annotation.AnnotationText="I need this value">
    ...
</prwab:work>
```

This is equivalent to:

```
<prwab:work>
    <sap2010:Annotation.AnnotationText>
         I need this value
    </sap2010:Annotation.AnnotationText>
    ...
</prwab:work>
```

So if you need a reliable way to read that, you should use the [`XamlReader` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xaml.xamlreader.read) (the one from the `System.Xaml` namespace - **not** the one from `System.Windows.Markup`). It works in a similar way to `XmlReader`, but normalizes the XAML it presents to you.

It won't be as straightforward as a linq query, but will be more reliable.